# Case Insensitive search in containment filter

Tags: django, filter

I need to perform Case Insensitive search in containment filter instead of using the exact case sensitve matching.

```
def filter(request, fname, fvalue):

    list = HmsPatient.objects.filter(**{fname:fvalue})
    c = {'list' : list}
    return render_to_response('patient/list.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST.get('filter_name')
    fvalue = request.POST.get('filter_value')
        return filter(request, fname, fvalue);
    else:
        action = HmsPatient().get_search_url()
        form = HmsPatientForm()
        c = {'form': form, 'action' : action}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response('search.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: the code is working fine, but the search is case Sensitive and Exact matching

Comment: i need to have a search which can enable me to have case insensitive and containment features..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Double quotes n "icontains" for case insensitive search.

```
def filter(request, fname, fvalue):

    key = fname + '__icontains'
    list = HmsPatient.objects.filter(**{key: fvalue})
    c = {'list' : list}
    return render_to_response('patient/list.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

use Double quotes n "contains" for case Sensitive search.

```
def filter(request, fname, fvalue):
    key = fname + '__contains'
    list = HmsPatient.objects.filter(**{key: fvalue})
    c = {'list' : list}
    return render_to_response('patient/list.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in MySQL chosing a collation makes the data values case sensitive, if u dont choose any collation your database will be case insensitive, i.e AbC =abc

Comment: django documentation provides all the necessary tools and instructions

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains

Answer (score 2):

Django allows you to do a case insensitive match using [`iexact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-iexact). For example:

```
Blog.objects.get(name__iexact="beatles blog")
```

In your case, because `fname` is a variable, you have to append `__iexact` to the key in your dictionary.

```
key = fname + '__iexact'
list = HmsPatient.objects.filter(**{key: fvalue})
```

Django also supports [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) and [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains), which you can use in the same way.

Comment: Exception Value:  

Cannot resolve keyword u'name_iexact' into field. Choices are: address, city, country, dob, email,

Comment: i had also tried
search_type= 'icontains'
key = fname + '_' + searchtype
list = HmsPatient.objects,filter(**{key:fvalue})
that also didnt work out

Comment: The first example `name_iexact` is from the docs. It won't work in your case because you don't have a field called `name`. For your second attempt, note that you should use **double underscore**. Please don't post extended code in the comments, it's really hard to read without whitespace. Update your original question instead.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair.. it worked perfectly with double underscores'__.
it solved the case sensitivity issue.
i shall try the "icontains" with doube undersores and update for containment.

Comment: Thanks **ALASDAIR**.using **double underscores solved my problem**